# TLP - battery status: Unkown (threshold may prevent charging) on Thinkpad with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, acpi, tlp

I've installed Thinkpad's utility for TLP (acpi-call) to set threshold and it seems to be working just I'm not sure if the info that TLP gives is the right one. I set startThreshold at 70% and stopThreshold at 75% - the TLP charged the laptop from below 70% to exact 74.5% and stopped there with information:

[image]

Moreover battery sign shows 74% all the time with info that the computer is charging but doesn't prompt any time left and it does not go up because of the threshold. Nevertheless is there something to worry about or that kind of behaviour is just normal? I mean the information from the TLP about current battery status from the above and the fact that battery icon does not change itself into "charged" status - are just fine? The laptop is Thinkpad L390.